# Spring Boot: @RequestMapping Priority

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping

My Spring Boot application encountered a problem as follows:

I have two `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{categorySlug:^[a-z0-9-]+$}/{slug:^[a-z0-9-]+$}")
public ModelAndView aTutorial(

        @PathVariable(value = "categorySlug", required = false) String categorySlug,

        @PathVariable(value = "slug") String slug) {

    // (1)
}
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/questions/**")
public ModelAndView fix404() {

    // (2)
}
```

I used (2) to redirect the 404 pages to homepage.

but when I go to the url like: `https://w3stacks.com/questions/fix`, i want it to (2) but it requests processed in (1), by `/questions/fix` coincides with `{categorySlug)/{slug}`.

So how do to it on (2), or in other words, can customize the priority between `@RequestMapping` or not?

Thanks.

Comment: I just tried removing the regex `/{categorySlug}/{slug}` but it stays on (1), @bureaquete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the `questions` word for `categorySlug` of `aTutorial` API.
Something like;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{categorySlug:^(?!questions)[a-z0-9-]+$}/{slug:^[a-z0-9-]+$}")
```

With that, you wouldn't get any call that starts with `questions` in `aTutorial` API like `/questions/etc`, but would also ignore `/questionsCategory/etc`

Hence `fix404` endpoint will be utilized properly as you have desired.

Comment: but it has to (2) does not? I want it to (2) to then redirect to the homepage - @bureaquete

Comment: Yes, the `@RequestMapping` I've given is for (1), so your call `/questions/**` can reach (2)